# Google Nest doorbell install - 6 wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, nest, doorbell

I’m trying to install a nest video doorbell, however I’m unsure how to wire it up as I cannot find a relevant wiring diagram. I have a Friedland 106 doorbell with one doorbell button at the front door. However there are 6 white wires? Can anyone shine some light on how to wire up the new doorbell, looking online 6 wires is normally for two doorbell buttons which I’m confused about as I only have one. Also the two terminals on the doorbell are not identified. Any help welcome. Thanks [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how to rate answers.

Comment: Could there have been a doorbell on the back door at one time and is now disconnected?

Comment: The pic is of the doorbell. Aren't you keeping that and only replacing the front button with a vid cam?

Comment: The nest doorbell attaches to the ringer as well as replacing the button.